# UINavigation Bar in worng position

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

i added a Navigation bar to the view using the folowing code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Load Colors"];
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:NO];
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(toggleEdit:)];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

    CGRect tableFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableFrame.origin.y = tableFrame.origin.y +45;
    self.tableView.frame = tableFrame;
}
```

as you can see in the picture below its comes on my tableView..
how can i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set your tableview origin.y to 45 so that the navigation bar wont come over the tableview

Comment: i tried this:   CGRect tableFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableFrame.origin.y = tableFrame.origin.y +45;
    self.tableView.frame = tableFrame;

but its no working..

Comment: can you tell me whats the frame of the tableview you have set?

Comment: i didnt set the tableView frame..
i edited my post, you can see my code there.

Comment: please try, self.tableView setFrame:CGRectFrame(0,45,320,height);

Comment: For getting your tableview.origin.y, you can display it using NSLog(@"%f",self.tableview.origin.y);

Comment: what should i pass in "height"?

Comment: Actually, i prefer to calculate the height with the screen size so that it would fine with any screen size. But for now, supposing you are trying it on a 3.5 inch screen, you could enter value 435.

Comment: are you sure you are changing the frame of the correct tableView? for debugging purpose, you could set the origin.y to a greater values like 100 or 150 just to check if this is making any effects. also you could try making some changes in the tableview to confirm that you are editing the correct table view

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect navframe = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];
```

Calculate the height of navigation bar using 'navframe.size.height' and set the TableView orgin 'y' to this height value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is appropriate in your case, but the best way to add a NavigationBar to your ViewController is to include your ViewController into a NavigationViewController. In this case you also don't need to worry about a correct transformation in case of device rotation.

I tried to implement it manually once (because I needed a navigation bar only on one view, so I thought that using a NavigationController would be an overkill). But in the end I removed all my code and used a NavigationController instead.

Comment: i cant use UINavigationController.. i just need a Navigation bar so i can add a buton to edit and go back.

Comment: Well, I don't know what can stop you from using it :) A similar case is described in the [Apple's tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH6-SW5). The only purpose they use a navigation controller there for is to add a navigation bar with one button ("Done").

Comment: Because in my root view (which has a NavigationController) i have a navigation button, when im clicking on the button its FLIP to another view..
i tried to make it navigationController but i always get exeptions..

Answer (score 0):

In the xib file you may provide space for navigation bar. The image below describes it.[image] Then you may add your tableview.

UINavigationBar is of dimension 320x44 for normal display and 640x88 for retinadisplay iPhone.

And use this code in the viewWillAppear

```
    //for custom navigationbar
    UINavigationBar *navBarName = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
    UIImage *backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"];// ur navigationbar image of above dimension
    [navBarName setBackgroundImage:backgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //for right edit button
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit:)];          
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
```